# Pass data between UserForms

Tags: forms, vba, excel, userform

Within Excel VBA I have a User Form similar to the following where the user enters an ID number and then the details are displayed on the user form:

```
Private Sub btnIDNo_Click()
Dim IDNo As Long
If txtIDNo.Text <> "" Then
    If IsNumeric(txtIDNo.Text) = True Then
        lblError.Caption = ""
        IDNo = txtIDNo.Text
        Worksheets("Details").Activate
        Range("B4").Select
        While ActiveCell.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value <> IDNo
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Wend
        If ActiveCell.Value = IDNo Then
            txtName.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            txtPhone.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Else
            lblError.Caption = "Cannot find ID nummber"
        End If
    Else
        lblError.Caption = "Please enter the ID Number in numeric form"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

On the Details User Form, I have an "Edit" button. Clicking the "Edit" button would open another user form where the user can change the details of that ID number, but obviously not the ID number itself. To do this, I need to pass the ID number from the Details User Form to the Edit User Form. Is there a way of doing this?

The bottom on the Show Details User Form to open the Edit User Form is similar to the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim IDNo As Long
If txtIDNo.Text <> "" Then
    If IsNumeric(txtIDNo.Text) = True Then
        lblError.Caption = ""
        IDNo= txtIDNo.Text
        ufmEditDetails.Show
        ufmShowDetails.Hide
    Else
        lblError.Caption = "Please enter the ID Number in numeric form"
    End If
Range("B4").Select
End If
End Sub
```

I have already looked at the following links but they don't seem to help:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671964-visual-basic-applications-pass-variables-between-user-forms.html

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/userform_pass_data.html

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html

Comment: Have you considered implementing your 2 current forms as a single form with a multipage control?  You can put the fields currently on your first form on page 1 of the multi page, and the fields currently on your second form on page 2.  You can make page 2 invisible by default and control within the code in the single form when you wish to display page 2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are many many ways... Here are some...

**Way 1**

1. Declare a `Public` Variable in a Module
2. Assign to that variable in Userform1 and then launch Userform2. This variable will retain it's value. Example

In Userform1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MyVal = "Sid"
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

In Userform2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox MyVal
End Sub
```

In Module

```
Public MyVal
```

**Way 2**

Use the `.Tag` property of the userform

In Userform1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm2.Tag = "Sid"
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

In Userform2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Me.Tag
End Sub
```

**Way 3**

Add a `Label` in Userform2 and set it's visible property to `False`

In Userform1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm2.Label1.Caption = "Sid"
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

In Userform2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Label1.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't the most simple way be `UserForm2.Txtbox.Text = UserForm1.txtIDNo.Text `

Comment: Yes it would be :) I answered the question "How do I pass data between User Forms?" As far as your answer is concerned, I  have already demonstrated a similar concept in `Way 3` :)

Answer (score 2):

There are serveral ways to solve this problem.
The one that I use is declare global or public variable in module

Example:

```
Public commonVariable As String
```

then in userform you can assign or retrieve value from this variable.
For example 
in userform1:

```
Private Sub btnIDNo_Click()
    commonVariable = "UserId"
End Sub
```

in UserForm2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    me.txtIDNo.Text = commonVariable 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest way is:

`UserForm2.TxtIDNo.Text = UserForm1.txtIDNo.Text`