# VBA: Passing a variable between functions for UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am creating a vba UserForm that after completion of the form, a string variable with the form details will paste into another sheet in the workbook.

I want to paste the value `dStr` into a new sheet after the use clicks on the addBtn. Would appreciate any help on this. I've read elsewhere that you can set the variable public, but not exactly sure how to do that either.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim valueUSD, name, ric, pStr, sitchStr As String
Dim i, lRow As Long

i = 2
ric = Worksheets("Tester").Range("H" & i)
name = Worksheets("Tester").Range("B" & i)
valueUSD = Worksheets("Tester").Range("C" & i)
sitchStr = ""
dStr = ""

pStr = ric & "   " & name & "   " & valueUSD & "   "

Label1.Caption = pStr

TextBox2.Value = ""

If activeCheck.Value = True Then
    sitchStr = sitchStr + activeCheck.Caption
ElseIf itwCheck.Value = True Then
    sitchStr = sitchStr + itwCheck.Caption
Else
    sitchStr = ""
End If

dStr = pStr & vbNewLine & sitchStr & ", " & TextBox2.Value

End Sub

Sub addBtn_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim myData As DataObject

Dim lastRow As Long


End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you define `dstr`? Also, the line `Dim valueUSD, name, ric, pStr, sitchStr As String` does only declare  `sitchStr`  as a string. All other variables will be of type variant, have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#How_to_Use_Dim_with_Multiple_Variables).

Comment: To set a variable to public, you can dim it with `Public` instead of `Dim`. You can do this outside of the sub it runs in. `Public var As String`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data between UserForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520558/pass-data-between-userforms)

Comment: Thanks guys, will give this a go!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the variable public works as Pluatian mentioned in the comment. To insert it into your desired worksheet you can use:

```
set pasteSheet = Application.Worksheets("Name of Paste Sheet") '<- input name of Sheet you want to paste it in

pasteSheet.Range("A1").Value = dstr '<- input cell you want to paste it in in Range
```

Or instead of the Range property

```
pasteSheet.Cells(1, 2) = dstr '<- 1 is the line number and 2 the Column Number, this example refers to Cell B1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private variable in your UserForm project (set your declaration(s) outside the Sub with private instead of dim)

if the variable needs to be used in other projects/functions: public variable or Property