# How do I add data from multiple user forms into a single row in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a user form in Excel that, depending on certain answers, launches other user forms. I am attempting to aggregate all of the input back into a central worksheet and on a single row. My issue is that the following code:

```vb
Private Sub AddCB_Click()
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox3.Value
```

Works great for the initial form but any data entered into the other user forms jumps to the next row. I realize why it happens but I don't know how to fix it. Essentially, I need the data from the other User Forms to populate cells on adjacent cells to existing data.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Seems like you could drop the +1, or (better) have your main form pass the row number to the following forms

Comment: Tim, tell me more! How do I pass a row number?

Comment: Why do you enter data destined for a single row in Excel in more than one user form?

Comment: It would help if you show the code where you open the next form.  Take a look here are try out one of the suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520558/pass-data-between-userforms

Comment: I use more than one user form because not every field is applicable. For instance, this is a client list. If they purchase, I have a radio button that launches another form for what they purchased, price, etc.  I don't want that if the client is simply a lead.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, one way would be to create a public variable.

```
Public CurrentRow As Long
```

Add this code at the top of a standard code module, before any procedures. Then assign a value to it in your first user form.

```
CurrentRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

You can now use the public variable anywhere in your project, like,

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value = TextBox3.Value
```

The value will not change until you assign another value to it which you can do in the same procedure as used previously or any other, anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 0):

if all "other" userforms are launched from a "mother" userform then you could have this latter pass the `lastRow` value to the formers using  their `Tag` property

So if the "mother" userform is of "UserForm1" class and a sub-form is of "UserForm2" class, you would have:

UserForm1 code

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastRow As Long


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' assuming a button event handler launches the sub-form of type "UserForm2")


    With New UserForm2 ' instantiate a sub-Userform of "UserForm2" type
        .Tag = lastRow ' write lastRow value into its 'Tag' property
        
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

UserForm2 code

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastRow As Long   


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    lastRow = CLng(Me.Tag) ' read the passed value into the local 'lastRow' variable
End Sub
```