# Referncing objects to be visible in Userform 2 if checkbox is checked in Userform 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble trying to make an object visible in one useform when the check box is checked in another userform. (e.g. Getting a label to be displayed in Userform 2 when the checkbox is checked in Userform 1)

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520558/pass-data-between-userforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just now I make a test.
Create two user forms : uf1 and uf2.
I make "Show Modal" to false on each user form property.
In uf1 I put two checkbox : cb1 and cb2.
In uf2 I put one label : Label1

Then I open both of the user forms.
Tick the cb1 in uf1, the Label1 shows in uf2
Untick the cb1, The Label1 is hidden in uf2.

[image]

If that's what you mean, the code is like this :

Sub in uf1

```
Private Sub cb1_Click()
If cb1 = True Then uf2.Label1.Visible = True Else uf2.Label1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Sub in uf2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Label1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Please note that the code in uf1 doesn't do error checking, for example : if uf2 is not exist (not showing) then .....

Answer (score 2):

### Objects in Another UserForm

- In both user forms, manually set the `ShowModal` property to `False`.

**`UserForm1`**

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    ShowLabel
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    If UserForm2.Visible Then CheckCheckBox
End Sub
```

**`UserForm2`**

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ShowLabel
End Sub
```

**`Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CheckCheckBox()
    UserForm1.CheckBox1 = UserForm2.Label1.Visible
End Sub
Sub ShowLabel()
    UserForm2.Label1.Visible = UserForm1.CheckBox1
End Sub
```